# Ubuntu disk space issue

Tags: ubuntu, linux-disk-free

There is some anonymous space consumption on my disk having Ubuntu. When I run the command df -h it shows me that total consumption is 5.4G. But when I run command du -hscx * on / directory it shows total consumption is 3.2G.

I am wondering where is rest of the space is consumed. Is there anything I’m missing? Want to free up that space.

I have searched all, tried different commands, but unable to find where the disk space is going.

Comment: This question belongs here http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journal takes some space.  So do inodes.  You didn't say which filesystem you're using.

Why `/*`, instead of `/`, though?  If you have any dot-directories in `/`, `/*` will miss them.

Use `du -scmx /`

Also, `du` won't be able to see any directories that are hidden by other filesystems mounted over them.